# SQL stored proc: How to detect whether optional output argument was passed or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure that takes one input argument and can return the related attributes via the optional output parameters. It is defined like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_get_info
                       @Identifier  nvarchar(50),
                       @Info1       uniqueidentifier = NULL  OUTPUT,
                       @Info2       nvarchar(10) = NULL      OUTPUT,
                       @Info3       int = NULL               OUTPUT
```

I would like to call the procedure like:

```
DECLARE @uid uniqueidentifier
...
EXEC sp_get_info @Idenfier = 'a123', 
                 @Info1 = @uid
```

Getting each output value leads to a different activity. This way, I would like to detect the fact that only the `@Info1` output value should be retrieved from elsewhere. This way, the procedure need not to execute possibly costly code that retrieves the other output (now unwanted) arguments.

Firstly, I was thinking about testing like `IF @Info1 IS NOT NULL  do_something`. However, as the OUTPUT says also that the argument can have also the input value (Microsoft SQL) the `@uid` itself can have the value `NULL`. This way, the above test does not work.

Is there any technique used to solve the situation?

Thanks, Petr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `@field` and `@value` parameter.  The `@field` could be `Info1, Info2, Info3`.  Now the `@value` can be `null` and you still know what field to search.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_get_info
    @Identifier nvarchar(50),
    @field nvarchar(50),
    @value nvarchar(50) output
```

The calling code would have to convert the `@value` from `nvarchar(50)` to the required type, but that's typically easy.

Comment: Thank you both. As there was a lot of attributes to be extracted this way, and it was apparently a kind of strange and complicated, I have decided to split that one stored procedure to several more specialised ones.

Answer (score 1):

Since the default value is a valid input, you can't tell whether it was passed explicitly or not.  You can add another parameter, e.g. `@Use_Info1 BIT`, to indicate whether a parameter should be used or ignored.